# Do two Eladrin both wearing a Circlet of Revelation auto-save on Charm effects?

Tags: dnd-4e

Eladrin have a +5 racial bonus to saving throws against charm effects.

The Circlet of Revelation head slot item grants the following:

> **Property**: While you have an eladrin ally within 10 squares of you, you gain a +5 item bonus to saving throws against charm effects.

Normally item bonuses and racial bonuses stack, but from a "I-think-too-much" standpoint it seems to not make sense in this case. The circlet lets you pick up the other racial traits of your party members. I wouldn't think you'd gain the racial benefit of your same race twice.

**Do two Eladrin both wearing a Circlet of Revelation get +10 to saving throws against charm effects?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes they do. Even though they are allowing others to use their racial bonuses, it is still classified as an *Item* bonus and therefore it stacks with the *Racial* bonus. It does indeed allow you to use your racial bonus twice.

Comment: Its a good question, and its a bit counter intuitive, but RAW this is the answer.

Comment: Agree. RAW it is how it works, though I'd probably houserule that a property you already possess would not be transferred.

Comment: @cthos: I assume if they wanted to prevent this they could have written, or released errata, that the bonuses are racial. Probably not a big priority, though.